# AppVeyor.yml not read during CI

Tags: continuous-integration, appveyor

At the moment I'm trying to figure out how to setup a proper CI using AppVeyor. The build is working fine, however AppVeyor seems to ignore my `appveyor.yml`. Moving it to a subdirectory and setting this over the Web UI didn't help either and the YAML file is also valid.

You can find the repository (with the appveyor.yml) [here](https://github.com/wallabag/windows-app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That project was added into AppVeyor as "generic" Git repository where `appveyor.yml` is not supported. Re-create the project as "GitHub" repository.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you please add this as a note to the documentation, I didn't found it in there :)

Comment: Sure, we'll do.

Answer (score 0):

You can also upload your `appveyor.yml` file to a third party server and link to it in the UI settings. Then it's picked up for CI